# How to mock the response for below code using sinon , mocha chai

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, mocha.js, sinon

Can anyone help me in writing one sample test scenarios?

`storage` is a library (google Cloud) finally below the line of code will return me an array consist of filename and Date.

```js
function abc(){
   const files = [];
   files = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();
   return files;
}
```

Comment: That is the neatest question I've seen in a long time! I'd also love to know how to write a test for such a case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
import { Storage } from "@google-cloud/storage";
const storage = new Storage();

export async function abc() {
  const bucketName = "xxx-dev";
  const files = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();
  return files;
}

export async function xyz(res) {
  const bucketName = "xxx-dev";
  return storage
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .file(res.fileName)
    .createReadStream();
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { abc, xyz } from "./";
import { Storage } from "@google-cloud/storage";
import sinon from "sinon";
import { expect } from "chai";

describe("59373281", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it("abc should pass", async () => {
    const getFilesStub = sinon.stub().resolves(["file1", "file2"]);
    const bucketStub = sinon.stub(Storage.prototype, "bucket").callsFake(() => {
      return { getFiles: getFilesStub } as any;
    });
    const actual = await abc();
    expect(actual).to.be.deep.eq(["file1", "file2"]);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(bucketStub, "xxx-dev");
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(getFilesStub);
  });

  it("xyz should pass", async () => {
    const fileStub = sinon.stub().returnsThis();
    const createReadStreamStub = sinon.stub();
    const bucketStub = sinon.stub(Storage.prototype, "bucket").callsFake(() => {
      return {
        file: fileStub,
        createReadStream: createReadStreamStub,
      } as any;
    });
    const mRes = { fileName: "jestjs.pdf" };
    await xyz(mRes);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(bucketStub, "xxx-dev");
    sinon.assert.calledWith(fileStub, "jestjs.pdf");
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(createReadStreamStub);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
  59373281
    ✓ abc should pass
    ✓ xyz should pass


  2 passing (46ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.spec.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

package versions:

```
"@google-cloud/storage": "^4.1.3",
"sinon": "^7.5.0",
"mocha": "^6.2.2",
"chai": "^4.2.0",
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59373281

Comment: Thank you @slideshowp2 , I have one more question . What if i have one function like below ,   storage.bucket(bucketName).file(res.fileName).createReadStream() .  I have tried writing this way but could not able to mock it .     const bucketStub = sinon.stub(Storage.prototype, "bucket").callsFake(() => {
      return {
        file: {
            createReadStream: getFilesStub
        }
    };
    });

Comment: Sure @SlideShowp, Thank you :-)

Comment: Hi @SlideShowp , Can you please help me with below test case .

Comment: @Tapas Ok, I will answer it.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to test for below code , I thought i will co relate but still getting error as file.on not functions :-(

```js
    function abc(req, res){
       const bucketName = "abc-xyz"
        const fileName = "Sample.json"
        var file = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName);
        const myfile = file.createReadStream();
        var  buffer = '';
        myfile.on('data', function(a) {
          buffer += a;
        }).on('end', function() {
          console.log(buffer)
           res.send(buffer)
        });
 }
```